# Cannot free up space using `sudo apt-get autoremove` on ubuntu machine

Tags: ubuntu

I'm using AWS Ec2 ubuntu instance. My machine storage is 100% full. I have added new volume but when I try to mount it it gives me error that cannot create temp file (no space left on disk). When I try to free some space using

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

it gives the same error.

Please help me how can I delete unwanted items and mount my new volume. What can be deleted from the root directory? I do not have any data outside of the root directory. My machine is just being used as a host to MongoDB database.

```
df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           396M   41M  355M  11% /run
/dev/xvda1       49G   49G     0 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop3       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/930
/dev/loop1       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1068
/dev/loop5       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6673
/dev/loop6       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/6818
/dev/loop2       18M   18M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/1335
/dev/loop0       89M   89M     0 100% /snap/core/6964
tmpfs           396M     0  396M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Using this command to attach the new disk

```
sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1
```

Comment: Do a `df -h` and include the output in your question.

Comment: @LawrenceC I have edited my question

Comment: Delete some files, e.g. from `/tmp` or some old logs from `/var/log` to free some space so that temp files can be created again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm semi late here but I have a very similar issue.  I wasn't trying to mount anything but every time I tried to deploy my application to my AWS ECS environment it would fail giving me this error:

```
STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: write /var/lib//docker/tm)

Status Reason CannotPullContainerError: Write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob775457260: no space left on device
```

In short I had to delete a lot of files from the **/var/lib/docker/tmp/** folder.

Prior to doing that I did a `du -h` on that folder and saw that it was much larger than other folders on my file system.

After removing 'x' amount of files from there I was able to have my deployed application run.